# I want lag function to only return if previous data is available

Tags: sql, oracle, function, hive, impala

[image: Sample Data is below]

In this example for 6th Jan lag will return apple, but i want this to be null because 5th Jan is missing, I need help for this give me idea or sql code in impala hive, I already have the code , but for 6th Jun it returns apple which is normal behavior of the lag function , but i need a trick so that the code can return null. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `max()` and `range`:

```
select t.*,
      max(sold) over (order by date range between interval '1' day preceding and interval '1' day preceding)
from t;
```

This is standard SQL but will not work in all databases.  So, a `case` expression might be simplest:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(date) over (order by date) = date - interval '1' day
             then lag(sold) over (order by date)
        end) as prev_days_sold
from t;
```

Date functions are notoriously database-dependent, so the syntax might be slightly different depending on the database.

Comment: I took the second one , because the first one was tool specific , though it was not easy because in my data there were apples , oranges and all other fruits, so needed to put that into partition , But thank you man, I hope I will return your favor one day by helping some one else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function `first_value` as follows:

```
Select date,
       first_value(sold) over (order by date 
                              range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as sold
  From your_table
Order by date;
```

Comment: Thank you Tejash, yes this works but I already implemented through the second technique in the above answer (which can be used in general not tool specific)